# Different results on displaying data from SQLite on android API 10 and API 23

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio-2.1

I am accessing a local SQLite database in an Android app to get a list of bird names and then they are displayed in a ListView.
I am using SQLiteAssetHelper to access the locally stored database.

---

While testing I noticed that differend devices gives different results.

- On Samsung GT-I9001 (Android 2.3.3, API 10) everything is displayed
  correctly.
- Testing on devices with newer Android versions
  (Samsung E5823 (Android 6.0, API 23) and emulator Nexus 5 API 23) not
  all data is displayed correctly

(examples displayed in screenshots)

[Samsung E5823 not displaying full title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slCYd.jpg)

[Samsung GT-I9001 displaying everything correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pJuk.png)

---

This is the code where I get the data from the database.

```
 public List<Specie> getNames() {
    List<Specie> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY LATIN ASC", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        String nameLT = cursor.getString(1); // this sometimes displayed not correctly
        String nameLOT = cursor.getString(2); //this is displayed corretly

        list.add(new Specie(R.drawable.ic_bird, nameLT, nameLOT));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

---

This is the array adapter code where the data is put to the list.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    SpecieHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new SpecieHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.txtTitle1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (SpecieHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Specie specie = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle1.setText(specie.titleLT);
    holder.txtTitle2.setText(specie.titleLOT);
    setImage(holder.imgIcon, specie.titleLOT);

    return row;
}
static class SpecieHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle1;
    TextView txtTitle2;
}
```

---

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

What could cause the differences between different devices and how could this problem be solved?

(Sorry if i didn't post everything needed for the clearance of the problem, I'll add if needed)

Comment: Try to change the font size in order to observe if this is a visual bug (which I suppose it is, kind of dropping what does not fit). Also I would recommend for debugging purposes to use different colors for layouts while you design them. Thus you will observe where  the problems are

Comment: I would advise you debug your data at first on line   String nameLT = cursor.getString(1); To understand, whether this is problem of DB, or just incorrect visualization. And checked item layout XML ( please provide it to question )

Comment: Can you post the Sql statements for the table creation ? Can you extract your database and browse it to see if datas are correctly saved ?

Comment: @ThomasV the database is created externaly with sqlite browser and put to the assets folder.

Comment: @XMight thank you very much, how did I not thing that this was a matter of  design? I noticed that the list items text view width was set to **fill_parent**, and when changed to **wrap_content**, everything was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was not with the database but with the design.

The text views width in the list_item.xml were set to **fill_parent**, and changing to **wrap_content**, solved the problem.

Comment: Well, wrap content and fill parent are very tricky things, in your experience you will see that sometimes you will use one, some other times you will use the other one. At the same time, I would recommend not to use wrap content, but use fill_parent where possible, and fix the parent layout, otherwise the layout will change depending on the content, which, usually, is not desired(in my experience). Also, if the comment was useful, please up-vote it!